# Nodejs - ZMQ Worker send data to http request

Tags: node.js, zeromq

I have a *http server* to serve so many connections. This server will get data from internet, or from disk, cache to response to client. I want to create some workers to do some job using ZMQ.

ZMQ server will send data to ask worker do their job like insert to db, write to disk and most important send data back to client.

Server :

```
   http.createServer(function(req, res) {
      ...
      zmq_socket_server.send(message);
   });
Worker : 
   zmq_socket.on('message', function(reply) {});
```

I don't know how to send data from workers to each client request .
Is it possible to do like that or any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple request reply pattern using the REQ and RES sockets.

Server:

```
var socket = zmq.socket('req');
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
   socket.send("send data");
   socket.on('message',function(reply){
       //worker sent back reply
   });
});
```

Client:

```
var socket = zmq.socket('rep');
socket.on('message', function(data) {
      socket.send("reply back here");
});
```

I have skipped out the obvious socket configuration part where you bind and connect to the socket address in each case, and I am assuming that you are using JustinTulloss's [zmq npm module](https://github.com/JustinTulloss/zeromq.node).

Comment: yeah, i'm using zmq like u said. When workers(client) get data , I want it send data directly to http request. Because data is big , I don't want main server do this.

Comment: @Windranger I forgot to add the code where the http server gets the reply from the worker. Added it now. The httpserver and the client can be running on two different servers if you have the correct network configuration on the socket connect and bind code. Do you want me to include that?

Comment: I 'm appreciate u care about it and I know what u said. But my problem is , I setup a server above , and client as a worker . I just want server as a controller , not send data at all (because it 's big work). And client do it , get data and send it back , not send back to server. Is it possible to do ? or client must send back to server then server send to client ? Or any solution to install a main process just call worker , then worker do all dirty work ?

Comment: now I install like your solution. But I got problem when socket server sends old message from previous http request. How can I disconnect previous socket when it done ? . And From server , socket req connect to socket rep when get request or connect before create server ? Waiting for your answer . Ty